# Get by code the path to Project's nuget packages

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying by c# code to copy some project's nuget packages to the project outputpath folder.

I parsed the packaages.xml file and got the path to the packages.

It looks like this:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Xdt" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

The problem is the **targetFramework**, in the package repository is

```
C:\Packages\Microsoft.Web.Xdt.1.0.0\lib\net30
```

and not

```
C:\Packages\Microsoft.Web.Xdt.1.0.0\lib\net40
```

So I need somehow to know to get the net30 folder instead of net40.
The Nuget Code itself knows how to do that and I tried unsuccesfuly to investigate the nuget.core code.

any help or idea would be appreciated.

**UPDATE :**

- why I need to copy the packages ? because we use **local copy false** on all the references
  due to build speed (not my desicion).

Comment: _"copy some project's nuget packages to the project outputpath folder"_ - why? Also, why do you know you need `net30`, is that because the project is built for .NET 3.0?

Comment: My packages has always been auto copied to the build folder.

Comment: @CodeCaster - the project is build for net40, but when there isn't a package direcotry for net40 but only for net30 I would like to take it instead of not taking anything.

The Nuget itself is doing it and I wanted to try to do that as well,
hopefuly using the nuget API.

Comment: Just so I understand what you're asking: Are you creating an msbuild task that will copy the contents of a nuget package to the output directory of your project(s)?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. You're essentially trying to replicate the 'local copy=true' functionality. Can you explain the reason for not using it?